Start 7Zip executable in a new process and pass encryption password in a secure manner
As the title mentions, I want to start 7z.exe and give it all the parameters, including a password, because I want to generate an encrypted archive.
In case it matters, I'm doing this on a Windows Server.
I've been trying all sorts of things, but the -p parameter refuses to accept anything but the plain-text password. The reason I can't have this, is because the command-line of the process might be visible to other accounts on the same server, and having a plain-text password in there is the last thing I want them to see.
Things I've tried so far:
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("7z.exe", "a ... -p%MYSECRET%")
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    EnvironmentVariables =
    {
        { "MYSECRET", password }
    }
};

var process = Process.Start(psi);
process.WaitForExit();

This one uses the literal '%MYSECRET%' as the password instead of the password variable's value.
Next attempt was letting 7z.exe prompt me for password and filling it in using standard input redirection:
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("7z.exe", "a ... -p")
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = true
};

var process = Process.Start(psi);

process.StandardInput.Write(password);
process.StandardInput.Close();
process.WaitForExit();

This one encrypted the archive with an unknown password. I tried to decrypt it with the actual one as well as an empty one, but none worked. My guess is that 7z.exe doesn't support anything other than interactive keyboard entry.
My question is: was I close with any of the methods or have I completely missed?
My next idea is to try building a simple BATCH file and executing it via cmd.exe to see if environment variable gets resolve that way. But I'm already pretty sure this would thwart my initial goal of avoiding the plain-text password in the command-line of the spawned 7z.exe process, because cmd.exe would replace the variable with its value before spawning the final process.
What else is there to try?

UPDATE
One additional way (which I was trying to avoid, if possible) seems to be building my own wrapper executable in C# that links the 7z.dll and invokes it via COM interface by passing the appropriate parameters.
As this would mean that I myself control the way the parameters are passed to my process, I could enforce the environment variable and avoid passing the plain-text password on the command line.
Now... Is this amount of effort worth it? Well... that will have to remain to be seen.
I'm still open to suggestions!

Apparently 7Zip overwrites the password in the args https://superuser.com/a/1358942

I saw this thread as well! But it doesn't seem to work this way with the latest 7z.exe build on Windows, so it's of no use to me. I've checked and I can clearly see the plain-text password in the "Command line" column in Task Manager while my 7z.exe command is executing. :( I suspect it's because programs cannot override their own command line once the process has started. It might be different on Linux.

I must say, I don't think this is really a risk unless the other malicious app is the same user or an admin, otherwise it can't see the command-line args for other users.

I can see what you mean. I do! But to me, this seems like an unnecessary exposure on a multi-user and multi-admin server, where who-knows-what scripts might be logging process details all the time and storing them who-knows-where. For example, were I to use my own compression app, I could have applied the password in any of the ways that I've tried and failed with 7z.exe. But since I can't realistically make a better/faster compression app than 7zip, I wanted to use that one. And then got frustrated by this limitation...

-p%MYSECRET%") Why do this at all? You have the password - just pass it here rather than use an environment variable.

Usually if the password is entered interactively you have to type RETURN/ENTER at the end to tell 7-zip that the password entering is now finished. I doubt that your password variable contains the necessary newline character. Thus I would add an process.StandardInput.WriteLine();

@Robert: This was actually the first thing I tried, intuitively. It didn't work... I then Googled a bit and came upon an MSDN link that claimed something along the lines: "When the stream closes, the (Close) command writes the lines ...". I admit I might have missed something, but since WriteLine() didn't do what I expected, I tried Write() + Close(). Sadly, still to no avail. The link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput?view=net-8.0#examples

It seems that if you know an archive is password protected and you don't want to specify the password on command-line you should not add any argument. 7zip will automatically ask for the password if you don't supply an extra argument. However if you just add -p extraction/decryption will fail. Just test it yourself on command-line using a password in a text file:  7z.exe x archive.7z < password.txt works.

@aoven StreamWriter class has a Flush method; you should call is instead of closing the stream.

@Soonts: All fine and well... I just followed the code example in the linked article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput?view=net-8.0#examples. :)
Yet, I can confirm neither Flush nor Close made any difference in my case. I believe it is because 7z.exe hooks directly onto Win32 keyboard input APIs and only accepts input from there and ignores the input from my redirected standard input stream.

@Robert: My main goal is to do this programmatically for compression, not decompression. And from C# code. Doing it manually from a cmd.exe shell is no good to me, because I know it works if I interactively input the password. It also works if I pass it in plain text as part of command line. It's just that.... I don't WANT to, because doing so also makes it visible when listing processes! Does that make sense?

May be the 7zip SDK is an alternative? No external command means no problem supplying the password.

@aoven Could be escaping or encoding, try 1234 or any other ASCII-only password without spaces. Could be timing, try to also redirect output text stream, read the “enter the password” prompt from there, and only then send the password to the input stream.
